# Extracting EC parameters to specified format

Tags: encryption

I have ECDSA public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
//public key data
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I'd like to create ASN.1 structure like this:

```
Parameters:: = CHOICE {
    ecParametersECParameters, namedCurveCURVES. & id( {
                                                     CurveNames}
), implicitlyCANULL}
```

and extract *Q* value. It is possible to extract such parameters from public key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `OpenSSL`:

```
$> openssl ec -in /tmp/blih -pubout | openssl ec -text -pubin

read EC key
writing EC key
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
pub:
    04:b0:36:49:b9:76:9a:1b:fd:72:1a:cf:22:d9:eb:
    29:e8:b4:fe:0b:fc:93:e6:35:9e:cd:c4:a0:15:00:
    27:49:af:40:8c:94:6c:50:58:da:e9:9b:88:61:83:
    34:d0:21:6d:03:b6:18:43:41:65:50:d4:db:d0:bb:
    75:8c:cf:fb:6f
Field Type: prime-field
Prime:
    00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:ff:
    ff:fc:2f
A:    0
B:    7 (0x7)
Generator (uncompressed):
    04:79:be:66:7e:f9:dc:bb:ac:55:a0:62:95:ce:87:
    0b:07:02:9b:fc:db:2d:ce:28:d9:59:f2:81:5b:16:
    f8:17:98:48:3a:da:77:26:a3:c4:65:5d:a4:fb:fc:
    0e:11:08:a8:fd:17:b4:48:a6:85:54:19:9c:47:d0:
    8f:fb:10:d4:b8
Order:
    00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:fe:ba:ae:dc:e6:af:48:a0:3b:bf:d2:5e:8c:d0:
    36:41:41
Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
writing EC key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIH1MIGuBgcqhkjOPQIBMIGiAgEBMCwGByqGSM49AQECIQD/////////////////
///////////////////+///8LzAGBAEABAEHBEEEeb5mfvncu6xVoGKVzocLBwKb
/NstzijZWfKBWxb4F5hIOtp3JqPEZV2k+/wOEQio/Re0SKaFVBmcR9CP+xDUuAIh
AP////////////////////66rtzmr0igO7/SXozQNkFBAgEBA0IABLA2Sbl2mhv9
chrPItnrKei0/gv8k+Y1ns3EoBUAJ0mvQIyUbFBY2umbiGGDNNAhbQO2GENBZVDU
29C7dYzP+28=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I believe `Order` is the `Q` parameter of the curve.

Also Keep in mind that you might not have the same output because the public key might not include the `EC parameters`, if not it is said "implicit parameters" because the recipient knows what curve and parameters to use. In this case you are out of luck if you don't know what curve it is.

If you know the curve you can extract the parameters using `OpenSSL` again:

```
$> openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -param_enc explicit -text

Field Type: prime-field
Prime:
    00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:ff:
    ff:fc:2f
A:    0
B:    7 (0x7)
Generator (uncompressed):
    04:79:be:66:7e:f9:dc:bb:ac:55:a0:62:95:ce:87:
    0b:07:02:9b:fc:db:2d:ce:28:d9:59:f2:81:5b:16:
    f8:17:98:48:3a:da:77:26:a3:c4:65:5d:a4:fb:fc:
    0e:11:08:a8:fd:17:b4:48:a6:85:54:19:9c:47:d0:
    8f:fb:10:d4:b8
Order:
    00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:fe:ba:ae:dc:e6:af:48:a0:3b:bf:d2:5e:8c:d0:
    36:41:41
Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
MIGiAgEBMCwGByqGSM49AQECIQD////////////////////////////////////+
///8LzAGBAEABAEHBEEEeb5mfvncu6xVoGKVzocLBwKb/NstzijZWfKBWxb4F5hI
Otp3JqPEZV2k+/wOEQio/Re0SKaFVBmcR9CP+xDUuAIhAP//////////////////
//66rtzmr0igO7/SXozQNkFBAgEB
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
```

Note the `-param_enc explicit` flag.